# Simplest github authorization for a command line application?

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

I have written a short command line application to automate some boring parts of my work that involve github.  It's likely that this utility script will be used 95% of the time by me, and 5% of the time by another developer - it does not need to be heavily productionized, and I can handle sharing authentication secrets myself, so I just want to create one secret which never changes and be done with it.

The script works perfectly well, except that on the last line I need to make exactly one call to the github API with method `POST`, and I believe that the authentication is failing, as I get a 404 result when I use `POST` but I don't when I try a `GET`.

Here are the details.

I'm using the popular Python library [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which I'm quite familiar with.

On GitHub, I created an OAuth App, and I copied the Client ID, which will be checked into the code, and the Client Secret, which is read in at runtime from a file that isn't checked in.

As per [this documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release), I then make a request to create a new release, passing in the authentication as follows:

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/rec/testy/releases'
data = {
    'tag_name': 'v1.0.1',
    'target_commitish': 'master',
    'name': 'name',
    'body': 'release body',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
}

res = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(res, res.text)
```

If I replace `requests.post` with `requests.get` I get the expected information about the releases, which is why I believe I'm doing the authentication wrong.

What's the simplest way to tweak my request to make this work, given that it's basically a one-off script for personal use?

Comment: I don't see the github documentation link you shared supporting a PUT anywhere, though it does allow for POST or PATCH (both of which are supported by requests). Are you sure you're not getting the error because the method PUT doesn't exist?

Comment: Ah, I typed in `put` instead of `post`.  Thanks for the correction, I'll fix.

Comment: This is done, and I committed code here: https://github.com/rec/BiblioPixel/blob/stack-overflow/scripts/new-release#L165-L177 so you can see what I'm actually running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a token: https://github.com/settings/tokens
In your data block use 

`'token': <YOUR_TOKEN>`

Instead of client_id and client_secret.
Alternatively, see this: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub